# My Java DiscoveryListeners aren't working. I can't detect nearby devices with Java

Tags: java, bluetooth, device

How can I debug my code? I don't see errors. It's been two days since I'm looking through this code, but I'm not getting what is not working. It seems I don't understand what it means to initialize a stack. I'm trying to discover all nearby [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) devices using Java.

```
package projet_bluetooth;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.bluetooth.*;

public class JavaBluetooth_1 {

    private static DiscoveryAgent dagent;
    private static myDiscoveryListener dlisten;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BluetoothStateException, IOException {

        LocalDevice device = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        device.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
        dagent = device.getDiscoveryAgent();
        System.out.println("Debut de la recherche de nouveaux périphériques ");
        dlisten = new myDiscoveryListener();
        Thread inquiryThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dagent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.LIAC, dlisten);
                } catch (BluetoothStateException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaBluetooth_1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        inquiryThread.start();

        // Wait for the thread to finish
        try {
            inquiryThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class myDiscoveryListener implements DiscoveryListener {
    int i = 1;

    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice rd, DeviceClass dc) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Nouveau périphérique: " + i + "-\t " + rd.getFriendlyName(false));
            i++;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaBluetooth_1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void servicesDiscovered(int i, ServiceRecord[] srs) {
    }

    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int i, int i1) {
    }

    public void inquiryCompleted(int i) {
        i = 1;
        System.out.println("La recherche est terminée!");
    }
}
```

However, the code always ends without getting new devices. I'm quite tired of checking by myself. How can I fix this?

I tried using threads to make sure the inquiry is effectively done.
I also tried creating a new DiscoveryListener-like object to pass it into parameters.

I asked ChatGPT how to fix the code, but the answers were vague (I don't quite understand them).

Comment: "projet" looks like [a typo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/project#Noun). Does it have any bearing on the result (e.g., some [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration))?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Project in French is Projet, idk about java, but the package name seems to be custom, and OP seems to be using french, based on the system out println message.